# Sencha Touch 2 - scroll list with other elements

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, scrollable

I have a view similar to this (this one is just an example):

```
xtype: 'container',
layout: {
   type: 'vbox'
},
items: [
   { xtype: 'some elements (actually this one is container, but it doesn't matter I think)' },
   { xtype: 'list', flex: 1 }
]
```

I need all this stuff to be scrollable together, but if I make list scrollable:false and set true of the same parameter to the parent container - it just cut down my content in the list.

Does anyone know what to do to make it work as I want?

Comment: You should add the container to your list directly. Take a look at PullRefresh.js to see how they add something at the top of the list.

Comment: Thanks, TDeBailleul for the reply! I've tried to understand logics of pullrefresh.js, but I can't figure out how this plugin adds the text above the list. Where is the line of code responsible for positioning pullTpl?

Comment: Actually it should be similar to scrollDock: 'top' parameter, but this parameter doesn't really do what I need because of a bug (some say that this is expected behavior: [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?256953-quot-scrollDocked-quot-items-inside-a-list-will-render-inside-the-first-list-item))

Answer (score 0):

You have done right by giving **scrollable : false** to **list** and **true** of the same parameter to the **parent container**.Now to prevent cut down of content in the list,you have use the following **css** **code**

```
.<yourListClass> .x-scroll-scroller,.<yourListClass> .x-scroll-container{
position:relative;
}
```